# I need to filter an Oracle SQL query on persons who turned age 21 during the calendar year of 2019

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

I need to filter an Oracle SQL query on persons who turned age 13 during the calendar year of 2019 - in other words, persons who had their 13th birthday sometime in 2019. Anyone know the code for that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your table has a `date_of_birth` column this would work (2006 being 2019-13):

```
select * 
from   your_table
where  to_number(extract(year from date_of_birth)) = 2006;
```

I notice your question title has a different year value from its body, so perhaps we need to hand over the troublesome maths to SQL:

```
select *
from your_table
where date '2019-01-01' = trunc(date_of_birth, 'yyyy') + interval '21' year
/
```

Truncating the DOB with a format mask converts all the dates to the first of January for that year. We then add an interval of 21 years. Comparing that value to the first of January 2019 will give you everybody who turned 21 last year.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `between` clause with `date_of_birth + 21 year` to let oracle use **index** on `date_of_birth`, if any as following:

```
select *
  from your_table
 where date_of_birth + interval '21' year between date '2019-01-01' and date '2019-12-31';
```

Cheers!!